# handle rest response(HATEOAS) with angular

Tags: angular, rest

I have a spring boot application with a rest api used as backend.
I want to use angularjs as frontend.

i get something like this as response from the api

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "genders" : [ {
      "name" : "male",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/genders/1"
        },
        "gender" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/genders/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "female",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/genders/2"
        },
        "gender" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/genders/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/genders{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/genders"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Angular part:

this is my gender.service

```
export class GenderService {

  private gendersUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/genders';


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  getGenders(): Observable<Gender[]> {
    return this.http.get<Gender[]>(this.gendersUrl);
  }
}
```

my gender model(do i need it?)

```
export class Gender{
    name: string;
}
```

my component

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  genders: Gender[];

  constructor(private genderService: GenderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGenders();
  }

  getGenders(): void {
    this.genderService.getGenders()
    .subscribe(genders => this.genders = genders);
  }

}
```

and how i use it

```
<ul class="genders">
  <li *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    {{gender.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The response is not an array and i get the following error

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

should i use map in my gender.service to handle that or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: From the response, an object is being returned. For *ngFor, it expects an array of object instead. Either change your api to return an array of obj or add object to an array .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the JSON that is returned by the API can't be parsed as an array. I managed to solve it by first unpacking the observable into an object, and then looping over the array *inside* the object.

```
<ul class="genders" *ngIf="genders | async as queerJsonObject">
  <li *ngFor="let gender of queerJsonObject._embedded.genders">
    {{gender.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

It might be more elegant to do this transformation inside your service. Feel free to share if you've figured out how do do this.